# How to get product purchased from Stripe PaymentIntent object?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a stripe subscription payment, and the flow is user clicks on a purchase button on my website, and is redirected to a stripe hosted page. After the user purchases, a webhook event is sent telling me that payment has been made.

I'm unsure how to get the actual product that was purchased as it's not appearing as line items in the payment intent. Is there a recommended approach? I could, for instance, store the product id in my local database, and then after the webhook, pull it from the local database. But this seems clunky.

Comment: It's actually not a bad idea to store the product ID in your database. That would reduce the number of API calls to Stripe. To go from Payment Intent ID to product is several API calls. You can get the invoice from the PI: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-invoice. Then product from invoice line item: https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/line_item#invoice_line_item_object-price-product.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the invoice, with its `id` which is in the `PaymentIntent` object. You will then obtain product information within the `lines` property of the `Invoice` object.

see https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve

Storing products in your database will force you to keep the stripe products and the products in your database up to date. You can retrieve all your Stripe products :

see https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/list

Answer (score 0):

You can pass metadata while creating your payment intent.

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
  amount=1099,
  currency='usd',
  payment_method_types=['card'],
  metadata={
    'product_id': '6735',// this can be anything stored to your db
  },
)
```

Hope this helps!